# delphi сравнить объекты узнать другой ли объект занимает туже память

Tags: delphi

```
var
  O: TObject;
begin
  O := Edit1;
  Edit1.Free;
  Edit1 := TEdit.Create(self);
  if O = Edit1 then   // true хотя хочу что было false как это сделать
```

и `O` это реально ново созданный `Edit1`

Comment: Свой менеджер памяти делайте. А реально это вряд ли принесёт пользу.

Comment: а для чего вам вообще вот это надо? а то вдруг, вы какой-то изощренный путь придумали для решения проблемы, которая вообще иначе может решаться

Comment: @teran
да просто не хочу от Tcompanenta наследоваться  что бы получать уведомления о удалении но пока другого способа не нашел.  Есть ссылка на контрол в другом модуле она как одна из полей простого объекта и когда я контрол удаляю и создаю заново та ссылка берет как в примере с O  новое значение контрола хотя по моим предположениям она должна была быть мусоркой но точно не другим котролом тем более рабочим

Comment: *"хотя по моим предположениям она должна была быть мусоркой но точно не другим котролом тем более рабочим"* - т.е. корневая проблема в том, что у вас ссылки на освобожденные объекты. Вот с этим и надо бороться напрямую, а не изобретать костыли.

Comment: не особо осилил без конкретики, но для подобных вещей нужны события и их обработчики.

Comment: @Kromster ваше напрямую и мое и еше какого васи слишком отличается. что конкретно хотите сказать. а в целом да так все. но пока решил взяв TComponent

Comment: Для ознакомления - https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/709

Answer (score 3):

Давайте разберем по шагам:

1. Вы запоминаете адрес объекта в `O` (TObject это по сути указатель)
2. Вы создаете новый объект и сохраняете его адрес в `Edit` (какой адрес он получит нам не подконтрольно)
3. Вы сравниваете 2 адреса (указателя)

Итого, про объекты в вашем сравнении ничего нет. А адреса могут как совпадать, так и нет, достаточно случайным образом.

---

Как же проверить, что объект по указателю новый?

Только храня где-то информацию об этом. Либо в неком общем диспетчере (записи вида "объект такой-то создан" "объект такой-то уничтожен"). Либо храня в самом объекте какой-то уникальный для него маркер (например автоинкрементный id, или например гуид).